# Serializing JSON object with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im trying to run to serialize the JSON response, but I am getting an error on the "let json = ..." line. The error is "Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)'". If anyone knows how to fix this I will apprechiate it

```
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value!, options: .allowFragments)

            } catch {
                print ()
            }

            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `response.result.value` is type of a dictionary `__NSDictionaryI`, not a Data as `jsonObject` expected. You can retrieve value from `JSON` with ease, no need to convert to json, for example: `JSON["title"]`

Comment: The issue is that accessing values like `JSON["title"]` is hacky and lazy. Your response JSON should be serialized into a swift object so that you can interact with it natively and have clean code.