# I cannot compile my alamofire code due to ambiguous reference to member jsonObject. Why?

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I have a code in `Swift` in which I'm calling through `Alamofire` my backend code:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: (parameters), encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
  .validate()
  .responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .success:
             do {
             if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
              for requestJSON in jsonData["geojson"]["features"] {
                  if let request = SingleCluster.fromJSON(JSON(requestJSON)){
                      let pinOne = CustomCluster()
                      pinOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude)
                      pinOne.amount = request.amount

                      self.eventsArray.append(pinOne);
                  }
              }
          }
             } catch let err{
              print(err.localizedDescription)
             }

          completionHandler!()

      case .failure(let error):
          print("error")
      }

}
```

The problem is that this line:

```
 if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
```

brings an error:

```
Ambiguous reference to member 'jsonObject(with:options:)'
```

I tried to cast it to `[String:Any]` or `[String:AnyObject]` but it didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps the following SO thread helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558133/serializing-json-object-with-alamofire

Comment: @Fahim yeah I've seen that, but because of lack of code snippet there in the answer I wasn't sure how to use this answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `responseJSON` with `Alamofire` so you will get Serialized JSON in the completion block, no need to use `JSONSerialization` use directly it.

```
switch response.result {
case .success:
     if let jsonData = JSON(response.result.value) {
         for requestJSON in jsonData["geojson"]["features"] {
              if let request = SingleCluster.fromJSON(requestJSON){
                  let pinOne = CustomCluster()
                  pinOne.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: request.latitude, longitude: request.longitude)
                  pinOne.amount = request.amount
                  self.eventsArray.append(pinOne);
              }
          }
     }
case .failure(let error):
      print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
```

To:

```
if let data = response.data, let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
```